# Azure WebApp Deleted and Domain is not accessable

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Unfortunately I deleted my WebApp, A domain which was purchased through azure portal by following these steps

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/

Was attached with this webapp. Now that I don't have any access to domain's DNS, If I  visit my domain it says

**This page is parked free, courtesy of Azure**

How I can get my domain back to me.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't lost your domain, so there's no *getting it back to you*. The issue is that you deleted your web app, so Azure is providing a **default landing page** for your now-unused domain name.

If you create a new web app, and want to assign your domain name to it, you should be able to in the ***Custom Domains and SSL*** blade for that web app's configuration.

For example, here's the settings for one of my web apps. I'd see my purchased domain names under **Managed Domains**.

[image: Custom domains and SSL]

Comment: Thanks @David But the problem is still there.

I created a new test webapp, But there comes nothing when I go there

http://i.imgur.com/q7v1hVh.png

Comment: @RawalBaig Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AqibBangash No, rather domain has been transferred to someone else I contact azure on twitter but they were not helpful at all.